# Request-Response logic

Tags: php, logic

```
    public function run() {
    /*
     * wrap uri in a decorator
     */
    $uri = new URI(trim(str_replace($this->base_path, "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), "/"));
    /*
     * fetch appropriate resource from uri
     */
    $this->resource = new Resource($uri);
    /*
     * prepare the request
     */
    $request = new Request;
    /*
     * get the response of the app based on the request
     */
    $response = $this->getResponse($request);
    /*
     * send response headers
     */
    $response.sendHeaders();
    /*
     * send response body
     */
    echo $response;
}
```

This is a "run" function for a web app framework I'm writing. Does my logic of request and response make sense? I'm not actually formally educated with programming. I just read a lot.

Comment: Could you describe in a little more details what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just trying to check if I understood requests and responses relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it makes sense to me -- but it's very vague without knowing your goald and seeing the code for these classes. It looks like the general process of handling a request broken down into the appropriate steps: parse the URI, find some content associated with that URI, send the headers of the content and send the content.

I'm not sure what you're using

```
$request = new Request;
```

for. Without seeing the class definition, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Oh, and

```
 $response.sendHeaders();
```

Won't work too well for you :-) You meant

```
 $response->sendHeaders();
```